# How to compare two CSV files and write non shared items to a CSV file in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have two CSV files like

CSVfile1.csv

```
Name,Identity,Location
Apple,45,Los Angeles
Banana,78,Kingston
Coconut,87,Thailand
```

CSVfile2.csv

```
Name,Identity,Location
Apple,45,Los Angeles
Banana,78,Kingston
Coconut,87,Wisconsin
Orange,48,Florida
```

The desired output

```
Name,Identity,Location
Coconut,87,Wisconsin
Orange,48,Florida
```

Is there a direct function to do it in R? New to R, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you also want "coconut,87,Thailand" in the output too? Please be more clear of what exactly you're trying to accomplish, as well as a reproducible example if possible.

Comment: @so13eit : No I do not want 'coconut,87,Thailand' in the output too. Thanks for asking. I want the differences as to csvfile1 and also what is missing in csvfile1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options to this in R. In base R, ususllay we use `merge` or `match`.

Another alternative is to use the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
## create sources from data frames
xx_src = tbl_df(xx)
yy_src = tbl_df(yy)
## to get shared items
inner_join(xx_src,yy_src)
    Name Identity    Location
1  Apple       45 Los Angeles
2 Banana       78    Kingston

## to get non shared items 
anti_join(xx_src,yy_src)
     Name Identity Location
1 Coconut       87 Thailand
```

where :

```
xx <- read.table(text="Name,Identity,Location
Apple,45,Los Angeles
Banana,78,Kingston
Coconut,87,Thailand",header=TRUE,sep=',')

yy <- read.table(text="Name,Identity,Location
Apple,45,Los Angeles
Banana,78,Kingston
Coconut,87,Wisconsin
Orange,48,Florida",header=TRUE,sep=',')
```

Comment: I want the differences in the sense as specified in the desired output where it will list the differences based on the csvfile1 and also list what is missing in csvfile1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Lines1 <- readLines("CSVfile1.csv")
Lines2 <- readLines("CSVfile2.csv")
LinesDiff <- setdiff(Lines2, Lines1)
writeLines(c(Lines[1], LinesDiff), "CSVfileDiff.csv")
```

This gives:

```
> readLines("CSVfileDiff.csv")
[1] "Name,Identity,Location" "Coconut,87,Wisconsin"   "Orange,48,Florida"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xx <- read.table(text="Name,Identity,Location
Apple,45,Los Angeles
Banana,78,Kingston
Coconut,87,Thailand",header=TRUE,sep=',')

yy <- read.table(text="Name,Identity,Location
Apple,45,Los Angeles
Banana,78,Kingston
Coconut,87,Wisconsin
Orange,48,Florida",header=TRUE,sep=',')


x <- rbind(yy, xx)
x[! duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE) & seq(nrow(x)) <= nrow(yy), ]
```

Output:

```
         Name Identity  Location
3     Coconut       87 Wisconsin
4      Orange       48   Florida
```

Credit goes to Matt:
[R selecting all rows from a data frame that don't appear in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427916/r-selecting-all-rows-from-a-data-frame-that-dont-appear-in-another)