# Delete values from a dataframe that also appear in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, `df1` contains many values and `df2` contains a few values that also appear in `df1`. The values in `df2` are ones that I want to delete from `df1`.

I have tried to do this by merging, but that doesn't seem to have an option to only keep values that aren't in both.

I also tried using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17428053/4572229) to a similar question.
This seemed to work, but it produced a dataframe with less values than I was expecting i.e. `df1` contained 74911 values, `df2` contained 767, and after removing them, there were 74064 remaining - so 80 additional rows were deleted. I'm not sure why this happened, if I could identify the 80 rows perhaps I could figure it out.

If anyone can think of an alternative way of achieving my goal I will be very grateful!

Here are some example dataframes, they are very simple compared to the real ones:

```
chrom <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
pos <- c(2, 7, 9, 14)
seq_c <- c('A', 'G', 'C', 'T')
seq_k <- c('G', 'C', 'A', 'C')
df1 <- data.frame(chrom, pos, seq_c, seq_k)

chrom <- c(1, 2)
pos <- c(2, 7)
seq_c <- c('A', 'G')
seq_k <- c('G', 'C')
df2 <- data.frame(chrom, pos, seq_c, seq_k)
```

Expected output would then be:

```
chrom <- c(3, 4)
pos <- c(9, 14)
seq_c <- c('C', 'T')
seq_k <- c('A', 'C')
df3 <- data.frame(chrom, pos, seq_c, seq_k)
```

Comment: Do you want to drop rows where the entire row is present in another data frame (as opposed to a single ID key value present in another data frame)?  That, and whether you have duplicate values of the key variable(s), could play a role in why more rows are being dropped than expected.

Comment: Ones where the entire row is present in another dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea using `merge()` and then removing from `df1` all row indexes that successfully merged with `df2`:

```
df1[-merge(cbind(df1,ri=seq_len(nrow(df1))),df2)$ri,];
##   chrom pos seq_c seq_k
## 3     3   9     C     A
## 4     4  14     T     C
```

And data.table has a nice elegant way of doing this:

```
library('data.table');
dt1 <- data.table(df1,key=names(df1));
dt2 <- data.table(df2,key=names(df2));
dt1[!dt2];
##    chrom pos seq_c seq_k
## 1:     3   9     C     A
## 2:     4  14     T     C
```

Note that the exclamation mark in the `i` argument to `[.data.table()` has a special meaning here; `[.data.table()` takes it to mean negation of the join against `dt2`, whereas normally it would negate each cell of the RHS data.table.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I got the expected 74144 rows. Thank you so much!

Comment: In the devel version of data.table, you don't need to set the keys, just use `on=`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `anti_join` from `dplyr` which will remove the rows that are common between 'df1' and 'df2', and keep only the rest.

```
 library(dplyr)
 anti_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: That sounds like a cool function, but dplyr is not available for my R version (3.1.1), and bgoldst's answer worked for me. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

I recreated your data.frame using stringAsFactors = FALSE, in that case, you can just use setdiff from dplyr:

```
chrom <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
pos <- c(2, 7, 9, 14)
seq_c <- c('A', 'G', 'C', 'T')
seq_k <- c('G', 'C', 'A', 'C')
df1 <- data.frame(chrom, pos, seq_c, seq_k, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

chrom <- c(1, 2)
pos <- c(2, 7)
seq_c <- c('A', 'G')
seq_k <- c('G', 'C')
df2 <- data.frame(chrom, pos, seq_c, seq_k, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% setdiff(df2)
```